# Laravel every page have a character on button

Tags: laravel

There is a special case in Laravel production server. There is a character "a" on button every page.
[image]

[image]

Or even in table.

[image]

and a very interesting thing is that when I load the page. It will show "a" again!

[image]

Those words are from lang/panel.php. However, I checked the file and I do not found any typo in the file. I also tried to clear cache and it is useless. Is there any way to solve this problem. I have no idea what wrong in this case. Local project does not have this problem.

Comment: Check the route file and the layout that extend all pages

Comment: There could be many reasons for this. It might be that the button is a component and its appending it. 

OR CSS can append text to content also.

Comment: Thank You for all answer. I checked the route file and layout file. Those file is ok. The CSS file is also ok. The most funny thing is that loading a page will show the character. I have not met the situation before

Comment: Check the begining of the blade file, in which you are creating the content, beginning with the button. Or in component file of Button ...

Answer (score -2):

I had a problem like that. All my pages had a caracter "a" on the top left corner. It was the first thing showed when pages where loaded. After searching in my code I found a "a" before "<?php" in the file .../config/mail.php